# Inequality of Partial Taylor Series

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, taylor-series, exponential-polynomials

Hi,

For a given $\theta < 1$, and $N$ a positive integer, I am trying to find an $x > 0$ (preferably the smallest such $x$) such that the following inequality holds:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{x^k}{k!} \leq \theta e^{x}$$

In my application, even $N$ is an integer function of $x$, i.e. $N = N(x)$, but for simplicity sake, let's assume $N$ is given for now.

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading

Fred

Comment: You won't find an exact answer.  However, the difference between the left side and $e^x$ is the tail of the Taylor series so can be expressed in many ways including as an integral.  Bounding that integral will give you bounds on $x$.

Comment: Thanks Brendan. I am going to play with this idea and see where I end up. Cheers

Comment: and in fact this idea will lead exactly to the inequality that William suggested, see her remark below. So I am still on the square one! :-(

Answer (score 2):

The approach that looks most promising to me here is to use the incomplete Gamma function, 
$$ \Gamma(n, x) = \int_x ^{\infty} t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt = (n-1)!e^{-x}\sum_{k=0} ^{\infty} \frac {x^{k}} {k!} $$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. From this and your inequality, we get that $\frac{\Gamma(N+1, x)}{\Gamma(N+1, 0)} \le \theta$, or, equivalently, that your inequality holds wherever $\int_0^xt^Ne^{-t}dt \ge N!(1-\theta)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks William,

This was a great observation. 

In fact, this inequality came out of a more general inequality involving incomplete Gamma function. I was, specifically, trying to bound the CDF of a Chi-Square random variable. I was hoping to make the problem simpler by going to the series format, rather than integral. Cheers.

Comment: The upper limit of the sum should be $n-1$ I believe.

Comment: yes that is true. But the last inequality is OK....have not got any further with this one yet?

Does anyone know of any tight upper/lower bound for the incomplete Gamma function?

Comment: Tight upper/lower bound will be difficult without further information. For instance, if you are interested in $\theta \ll 1$, then $x$ will be large and you could try to use asymptotic approximations like http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11
